# C# DateTime format for 2013-12-16T11:20:57+0530

Tags: c#

What is the correct format for the datetime to get the following output.

Output : 2013-12-16T11:20:57+0530

Comment: Is time 24 hour format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that:

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Now;
string dtoString = dto.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz");
dtoString = dtoString.Remove(dtoString.Length - 3, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But am getting : in between 05 and 30..It's like 05:30..It should actually 0530

Comment: See my edit. There's no format for it but you can remove that manually.

Answer (score 2):

Format would be "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz"

```
var result = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz");
result = result.Remove(result.LastIndexOf(':'), 1);
```